# ubuntu php with freetds connecting to mssql on another system

Tags: php, sql-server, ubuntu, freetds

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and i have installed freetds and odbc taking guidance from this link : http://www.bictor.com/2014/05/13/configure-unixodbc-for-ubuntu-14-04-using-freetds/

The database i am trying to connect to is on another system (mssql 2008 r2 express server) .

When i try to connect to that system database using the : `isql -v test` command . 
When i do that i get the below errors :

```
> [S1000][unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unable to connect to data source
> [01000][unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unknown host machine name.
> [ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect
```

My odbc.ini file looks like this :

```
[test]
Driver = FreeTDS
Description = My Test Server
Trace = No
ServerName = HOME-PC\ZOLIPE
Port = 1433
Database = test
TDS_Version = 4.2 (This version is the same as reported by tsql -C command)
```

i have also added the below in my freetds.conf file :

```
[mssql]
host = HOME-PC\ZOLIPE
Port = 1433
tds version = 4.2
```

Please help and thanks in advance .

Comment: No takers ? Seems like noone knows anything about ubuntu and mssql.Great

Comment: First, did you verify that you can connect from the network? SQL Server Express has networking disabled by default. Second, can you ping `HOME-PC` from your Ubuntu machine?  You may need a fully qualified name.  Third, did you create an `/etc/odbcinst.ini` file? If so, what's in it?  Also, you'd typically use [TDS_Version 7.2](http://www.freetds.org/userguide/choosingtdsprotocol.htm) for 2008R2.

Comment: try to add a line with the IPv4 Address of HOME-PC to your hosts file. The full path is c:\windows\system32\etc\drivers\hosts. Read the comments in the file and create a custom copy of one of the commented entries provided.